# Return value in a rang() loop with python

Tags: loops, return

```
def power(num, x):
result = 1;
for i in range(x):
    result = result *num
    return result
```

print power(4,3)

after over-indentation "return result", the output of the execution is "4". I thought it would be 4,16,64 seperately. what is the wrong there? Anyone can give me a clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It jumps out in the first loop runtime until meet return rather other continuing looping.